# htaccess file to forward old domain to new one

Tags: .htaccess

I'm really struggling to overcome an issue with htaccess that I'm after some help with. We have recently changed domain names so wanted to redirect all traffic coming into the old site to the new one, the following is our htaccess file which accompanies that fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# if requested hostname is non-blank
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# and if requested hostname is NOT &#34;newdomain.com&#34;
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bigcarclub\.com
# redirect to same object in correct domain
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bigcarclub.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.bigcarclub.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, also residing on this server is a very old legacy site that sits in a folder off the root that we have to keep. It has its own domain name (mirez co uk) however the htaccess file is also now redirecting that one to our new domain. I've played about with various iterations but I can't get it to work without breaking the forwarding of the new site.

Please help! :)

Comment: Why are you doing this by trying to check that the host name is _not_ the new domain then, instead of doing it the other way around, by checking if it _is_ the old domain?

Comment: Simple - My limited htaccess skills!! So this was a template I found on the web to accomplish the task.

Comment: Just add a RewriteCond that makes sure the host name is not `mirez.co.uk` either then, that should work. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mirez\.co\.uk` (And the condition checking for a "non-blank" host name can be removed, I think. Even if the page was requested via an IP adress instead of a domain name, then HTTP_HOST should contain that IP address instead.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, that seems to have done it :)